# How to add a circle to ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview.I want to put texts and a circle filled with specific color in listview items.Text are different but circle should have one color only.Anyone having idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html), override its `getView()` method and return any view you want. Usually `BaseAdatper` or `ArrayAdapter` classes are used as the base class. Then you need to attach this adapter to the `ListView` using `ListView.setAdapter()` and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a shapedrawable for the view of circle and create your own custom adapter (for example see link http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html